# Question on the Apex setEndpoint path using a callout

Tags: apex, callout

I'm trying to figure out what the target should be for the 'some_path' path from the Named Credential [example code](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_named_credentials.htm). Should it be specifically targeting the API location for my third-party REST provider or would this be a shortcut to browse the URL structure of the third-party since the API key is given?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a shortcut. For example, let's say you wanted a Google search:

```
Named Credential URL:
https://www.google.com/search
```

Then the endpoint to search would become:

```
callout:googlesearch?q=abcd
```

This behavior allows the endpoint to change without having to change all of your code.

Comment: I see. So, it's whatever you define going forward, but best to explicitly target a service in the Named Credential URL. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Named credentials should be the base url, You can append any URI at runtime and reach any third party service.

```
req.setEndpoint('callout:My_Named_Credential/' + uri);
```

or if you want to hard code

```
req.setEndpoint('callout:My_Named_Credentialmybatch?q=22' );
```

Source: http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/salesforce-to-salesforce-integration-using-named-credentials-in-just-5-lines-of-code/

Comment: Yes, that I'm aware of. So, the URI part can only target individual services, not the individual paths and directories of a 3rd-party provider?

Comment: They can point to paths and directories. If there is no web service it would return the HTML associated