# Apex setEndpoint returning Bad Response - 401

Tags: apex, api, integration, connected-apps, namedcredentials

I am trying to make a GET request:

```
public class SalesforceConnect {
    public static String getCasesFromSalesforceOrgB() {
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint('callout:SFDCB/services/apexrest/Cases');
        request.setMethod('GET');
        System.debug('Request URL!!!!!! => ' + request.getEndpoint());

        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
        System.debug('Status Code => ' + response.getStatusCode());
        if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            System.debug('Good Response => ' + response.getBody());
            return response.getBody();
        } else {
            System.debug('Bad Response');
            return 'Bad Response';
        }
    }
    
}
```

My Named Credentials:

---

Name: SFDCB

---

Label: SFDCB

---

---

---

```
Identity Type:  Named Principal
Authentication Protocol: OAuth 2.0
Authentication: Provider    SalesforceOrgB
Scope:  refresh_token full
Authentication Status:  Authenticated as test-gsxmjtjhwz134l3e@example.com
```

And still I am getting Bad Responce

I have checked with this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/219139/question-on-the-apex-setendpoint-path-using-a-callout) even, same results.

Comment: 401 is unauthorized. This may be because the provile assigned to user test-gsxmjtjhwz134l3e@example.com does not have access to the apex class that is exposing the API in org B...